# Mudar imagens de um PictureBox C# - Windows Form Aplication

Tags: c#, winforms

Boa Tarde Pessoal,

É o seguinte, estou trabalhando com Windows form e criando uma aplicação simples que possui um botão "carregar" que abri uma janela para selecionar uma imagem no picturebox, o código ficou assim:

```
private void carregarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //verifica se a imagem foi carregada 
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //seleciona a imgaem e vincula a mesma ao pictureBox chamado "exibirImagem"
            exibirImagen.ImageLocation = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            //carrega a imagem selecionada no Picture box "exibirImagem"
            exibirImagen.Load();
            //salva o caminho da imagem selecionada em uma string
            caminhoImagem = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }
```

até aqui para carregar a imagem tudo bem. **A duvida é a seguinte**, como posso fazer para "passar" para próxima imagem, por exemplo, supondo que dentro da pasta que selecionei a imagem1.jpg existe também a imagem2.jpg, quero clicar em um botão chamado próximo ele carrega a imagem2.jpg no picturebox. Se alguém puder ajudar, da alguma ideia, postar algum link que ajude desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode pegar os arquivos da pasta e passar no botão de próximo da seguinte forma. Deixei um método para caso queira fazer um botão de voltar também.

Adicione uma variável para guardar o índice da imagem que está sendo apresentada.

```
private int _indiceImagem = 0;
private string[] _imagens = Directory.GetFiles(caminhoFotos, "*.jpg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

public void PassarParaProximaFoto()
{
    _indiceImagem++;

    if (_indiceImagem > _imagens.Length - 1)
         _indiceImagem = 0;

    pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(_imagens[_indiceImagem]);
}

public void VoltarParaFotoAnterior()
{
    _indiceImagem--;

    if (_indiceImagem < 0)
         _indiceImagem = _imagens.Length - 1;

    pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(_imagens[_indiceImagem]);
}
```

Comment: Olá Pedro, agradeço muito sua resposta, resolveu meu problema. Só tive que fazer alguns ajustes conforme minha necessidade, mas era exatamente isso que eu procurava, muito obrigado novamente.

Comment: Por nada, qualquer dúvida estou à disposição.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser fazer um slid sem botão de acordo com as imagens no diretório que você colocar, com componente timer configurado de acordo com segundos que você setar, e só fazer esse metodo logo abaixo e colocar o metodo no evento do timer:

Metodo:

```
private void CarregarImagemSlider()
    {
        try
        {
            //Declare uma varial fora do scopo do metodo na class principal com nome ImagemNumero = 1;
            string s = @"C:\ImagensSlider\"; //Diretorio das imagens
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo d = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(s);
            int files;
            files = d.GetFiles().Length;//Pega a quantidade de imagens no diretorio
            if (ImagemNumero == files)//As imagens deve ser renomeadas com numero 1.png,2.png.... na sequencia que você quiser
            {
                ImagemNumero = 1;
            }
            pictureBoxSlider.ImageLocation = string.Format(@"C:\ImagensSlider\{0}.jpg", ImagemNumero);
            ImagemNumero++; //Passa pra próxima imagem depois de percorrer os segundos do timer..
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            //Codigo exception aqui Ex: messagembox
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Voce deve ter uma lista com todos os caminhos das imagens no diretório que você selecionou.

algo do tipo:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo("DiretorioAqui");

        List<string> imagens = directoryInfo.GetFiles().Where(s => s.Extension.ToLower() == "png" || s.Extension.ToLower() == "jpg").Select(s => s.FullName).ToList();
```

Tendo isso em maos fica facil, comece exibindo o index 0 da lista:

```
string caminhoImagem = imagens[0];
```

Ao clicar em "Proxima", por exemplo, voce passa a exibir o index 1, e assim por diante. Esse index deve ser controlado por uma variavel, a qual você irá incrementar ou decrementar, conforme a necessidade.

Comment: Olá Filipe, obrigado pela sua resposta, tenho mais uma dúvida, ali na parte do código onde você coloca ("DiretorioAqui"), no caso eu consigo esse diretório através da minha variável  openFileDialog1? se sim, como eu posso fazer, pq até agora eu só consegui recuperar o caminho completo até a imagem, mas "apenas" o caminho do diretório não. Agradeço novamente a ajuda.

Comment: Pode usar um FolderBrowserDialog:                           
       FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

            fbd.ShowDialog();

            string caminho = fbd.SelectedPath;